# Ubuntu 19.04 goes to Read-Only mode automatically

Tags: filesystem, 19.04, disk, fsck, read-only

In my Ubuntu 19.04, the system goes read-only mode automatically. I fixed it using 
`fsck /dev/sda7 -y`
But it is not fixed permanently after some time it goes to read-only mode again.

I am using dual booted system with windows 10 installed. This is the information of the disk

[image]

This is the export of the disk info , including SMART info

```
*** DiskCheckup V3.4 Build: 1003 Report ***

SysInfo DLL Version:                                                  SysInfo v1.0 Build: 1122
Time of export:                                                       10:24:41 12-Nov-2019

Device information:                                                   
   Device ID:                                                         0
   Interface:                                                         SATA
   Device Capacity:                                                   953867 MB
   Serial Number:                                                     Y65NTEY0T
   Model Number:                                                      TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
   Firmware Revision:                                                 AX1R4C
   Partitions:                                                        
      C:         243053 MB
      F:         240198 MB

ATA information:                                                      

   Disk geometry:                                                     
      Cylinders:                                                      121601
      Tracks/Cylinder:                                                255
      Sectors/Track:                                                  63
      Bytes/Sector:                                                   512
      Total disk sectors:                                             1953525168
      Logical sector size:                                            512
      Physical sector size:                                           4096
      Media rotation rate:                                            5400 RPM
      Buffer size:                                                    8192 KB
      ECC size:                                                       N/A

   Standards compliance:                                              
      ATA8-ACS Supported:                                             Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-7 Supported:                                          Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-6 Supported:                                          Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-5 Supported:                                          Yes
      ATA/ATAPI-4 Supported:                                          Yes
      SATA Compliance:                                                Yes
         SATA Gen3 Signaling Speed (6.0Gb/s) Supported:               Yes
         SATA Gen2 Signaling Speed (3.0Gb/s) supported:               Yes
         SATA Gen1 Signaling Speed (1.5Gb/s) supported:               Yes
      Transport Type:                                                 Serial
         SATA 3.0 Transport Compilance:                               Yes
         SATA 2.6 Transport Compilance:                               Yes
         SATA 2.5 Transport Compilance:                               Yes
         SATA II: Ext Transport Compilance:                           Yes
         SATA 1.0a Transport Compilance:                              Yes
         ATA8-AST Transport Compilance:                               Yes
   World Wide ID:                                                     5000039761B01D1D

   Feature support:                                                   
      SMART supported:                                                Yes
         SMART enabled:                                               Yes
      SMART self-test supported:                                      Yes
      SMART error log supported:                                      Yes
      LBA supported:                                                  Yes
      IORDY supported:                                                Yes
      CFast supported:                                                No
      DMA supported:                                                  Yes
         Maximum Multiword DMA mode supported:                        2
         Multiword DMA selected:                                      None
         Maximum UltraDMA mode supported:                             5
         UltraDMA selected:                                           5
      Maximum PIO mode supported:                                     4
      SATA Compliance:                                                Yes
         NCQ priority information supported:                          No
         Unload while NCQ commands are outstanding supported:         Yes
         Phy Event Counters supported:                                Yes
         Receipt of power management requests supported:              No
         NCQ feature set supported:                                   Yes
         Software Settings Preservation:                              Supported, Enabled
         In-order data delivery:                                      Not supported
         Initiating power management:                                 Supported, Disabled
         DMA Setup auto-activation:                                   Supported, Disabled
         Non-zero buffer offsets:                                     Not supported
      Trusted Computing supported:                                    No
      Host Protected Area (HPA) supported:                            No
      Read look-ahead supported:                                      Yes
         Read look-ahead enabled:                                     Yes
      Write cache supported:                                          Yes
         Write cache enabled:                                         Yes
      Power management supported:                                     Yes
      Security mode supported:                                        Yes
         Security mode enabled:                                       No
      Device Configuration Overlay (DCO) supported:                   Yes
      48bit Addressing supported:                                     Yes
      Auto Acoustic Managment (AAM) supported:                        No
      Power-up in Standby (PUIS) supported:                           Yes
         Power-up in Standby (PUIS) enabled:                          No
      Advanced Power Management (APM) supported:                      Yes
         Advanced Power Management (APM) enabled:                     Yes
         Current APM level:                                           Minimum power consumption without Standby
      CompactFlash Association (CFA) supported:                       No
      General Purpose Logging (GPL) supported:                        Yes
      Streaming supported:                                            No
      Media card pass through supported:                              No
      Extended power conditions supported:                            No
      Extended status reporting supported:                            No
      Write-read-verify supported:                                    No
      Free-fall control supported:                                    No
      TRIM command supported:                                         No
      SCT command transport supported:                                Yes
      NV Cache enabled:                                               No
      NV Cache Power Management supported:                            No

SMART ATTRIBUTES:
 ID Description                             Status      Value       Worst       Threshold   Raw Value   TEC                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 Raw Read Error Rate                     OK          100         100         50          0           N/A                 
  2 Throughput Performance                  OK          100         100         50          0           N/A                 
  3 Spin Up Time                            OK          100         100         2           772         N/A                 
  4 Start/Stop Count                        OK          100         100         0           14107       N/A                 
  5 Reallocated Sector Count                OK          100         100         10          0           N/A                 
  7 Seek Error Rate                         OK          100         100         50          0           N/A                 
  8 Seek Time Performance                   OK          100         100         50          0           N/A                 
  9 Power On Time                           OK          77          77          0           9576        N/A                 
 10 Spin Retry Count                        OK          253         100         30          0           N/A                 
 12 Power Cycle Count                       OK          100         100         0           6541        N/A                 
183 SATA Downshift Error Count              OK          100         100         1           0           N/A                 
184 End-to-End error                        OK          100         100         97          0           N/A                 
185 Head Stability                          OK          100         100         1           65535       N/A                 
187 Reported Uncorrectable Errors           OK          1           1           0           1294        N/A                 
188 Command Timeout                         OK          100         98          0           16          N/A                 
189 High Fly Writes                         OK          100         100         1           0           N/A                 
190 Temperature Difference from 100         OK          63          48          40          639238181   N/A                 
191 G-sense Error Rate                      OK          100         100         0           1059        N/A                 
192 Power off Retract Count                 OK          100         100         0           29032891    N/A                 
193 Load Cycle Count                        OK          92          92          0           83346       N/A                 
194 Temperature                             OK          63          48          40          37 C        N/A                 
196 Reallocation Event Count                OK          100         100         0           0           N/A                 
197 Current Pending Sector Count            OK          100         100         0           1456        N/A                 
199 UltraDMA CRC Error Count                OK          200         200         0           0           N/A
```

Is there any permanent fix to it?

Comment: It's only 3 years since I bought my laptop. How can it dye so early ?

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, have you installed any Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app SMART Data window... lets check your HDD.

Comment: @SorenA how can you say it's a bad HDD without any data to support that?

Comment: @heynnema I have added the information you needed, please check.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Before I give you my recommendations, please answer the first question in my prior comment. Also, give me the make and model # of your laptop. Do you have good backups? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have dual booted with windows, and I do not have good backups.

Comment: @heynnema The laptop I am using is HP 15-ay542tu.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Have you installed any Windows drivers that allow you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Is your boot disk HDD or SSD? Are you able to perform any backups of important files at all?

Comment: I am not sure about the drivers. Disk is HDD. I cannot do the backups.

Comment: status please...

Comment: @heynnema since the system is read-only, I am unable to download anything, so I cannot donwload the software you recommended and also I have no backup so cannot perform the operations you mentioned.

Comment: If you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB you can do both, including some backup to an external HDD or USB flash drive. If your HDD is indeed failing, doing nothing will only lose all of your data.

Comment: status please...

Comment: @heynnema I have found that my HDD have some bad blocks, I used e2fsck -c to add all the bad blocks to the bad blocks list, which will prevent the OS to allocate these damaged sectors. After doing this the system is working fine.

Comment: Great news! That's what my answer said to do. You should have used the second command. The -k parameter should have been used. Please remember to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. You can also click on the up arrow. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema will it have any similar situation in future also ?

Comment: It's possible, depending on if your hard disk is actually failing. Be sure to use the second command in my answer... as your method using only -c didn't preserve the prior bad block table, and didn't read/write. Keep good backups.

Comment: @heynnema I tried doing backup using 2 ways, 1st one using bootable usb and using disks utility gui and clicking on create disk image, but I was not able to do so, there was some error message. 2nd  way that I tried is to use sudo tar czf /backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/dev --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/lost+found /
 but It took a lot of space and I was left will little space on my device, so I aborted this process too.

Comment: @heynnema Can u suggest some good way to backup my system ?

Comment: You can't... ie: you don't want to... trying to save backups on the same disk as might be failing. It should be an external USB disk or flash drive. Then you can use the built-in `Backups` app to backup your home folder.

Comment: @heynnema how much space will the tar backup take to backup about 250gb of disk ?

Comment: If you're going to backup a 250G disk, either an **image** or **clone** backup would be best. You can use the `Disks` application to do **image**. `clonezilla` may be able to do **clone**, depending on the size of your target disk.

Comment: If you wish to just backup a partition, `gparted` or `clonezilla` can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a dual-approach to resolving your problem...

**Memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete.

**Bad Block the HDD**

Note: If your HDD is failing, performing this procedure without any backups is not recommended. Even backing up to a USB flash drive is better than nothing.

These are the important data points that I'm looking at...

```
SMART ATTRIBUTES:
 ID Description                             Status      Value       Worst       Threshold   Raw Value   TEC                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 Raw Read Error Rate                     OK          100         100         50          0           N/A                                  
187 Reported Uncorrectable Errors           OK          1           1           0           1294        N/A                 
196 Reallocation Event Count                OK          100         100         0           0           N/A                 
197 Current Pending Sector Count            OK          100         100         0           1456        N/A
```

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fsck -f /dev/sda7` # clean up the file system first

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sda7` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sda7` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.

   -y     Assume  an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
          used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the
          same time as the -n or -p options.
```